# How to change shape color programmatically for a homescreen widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I want my homescreen widget to be a rectangle with corners so I have a shape drawable. The solid color, however, needs to change on the press of a button to match my text background color. I am able to change my text background color in this way:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

backgroundColor = colors[mCounter];
views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_text, "setBackgroundColor", backgroundColor);
```

I tried the following but no luck:

```
views.setInt(R.drawable.layout_bg, "setBackgroundColor", backgroundColor);
```

I have also tried changing the backgroundTint of my widget, and the following:

```
views.setInt(R.id.appwidget_layout, "setBackgroundTint", backgroundColor);
```

This does not do anything either.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I also need a rounded background that changes color dynamically for my widget.

Comment: No, in the end I made my widgets with straight corners and gave up on trying to give them a rounded shape... From Android 12, they are automatically rounded by the system anyway. But not everyone's on 12, of course.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] color = new int[2];
color[0] = Color.parseColor("#000000");
color[1] = Color.parseColor("#000000");

View view = new RelativeLayout(this);
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();

drawable.setColors(color);
```

try this. for your problem,

```
int[] color = new int[2];
color[0] = Color.parseColor("#000000");
color[1] = Color.parseColor("#000000");
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) views.getBackground();
drawable.setColors(color);
```

hope it will helps. :)

Comment: Thank you but getBackground() is not an option for views (as in Remote Views).

Comment: i see bro. i will try it too.